# Rabbitmq with python works unexpected

Tags: python, rabbitmq, message-queue

I am working with rabbitmq to do some practice .

But the rabbmitmq behavior is different from tutorial on official website.

The `worker` and `task_sender` use following code to connect with rabbitmq.

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='task_queue')
```

And `task_sender` send task by calling

```
for i in range(10):
    message = "job%s %d %s" % (str(random.randint(1,10)), i , '.'*i)
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='task_queue',
                      body=message,
                      properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                         delivery_mode = 2, # make message persistent
                      ))
```

and the `worker` get tasks by calling and wait some time .

```
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] Received %r" % body)
    time.sleep(body.count(b'.'))
    print(" [x] Job Done!")
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)


channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue='task_queue',
                      no_ack=True)

print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
channel.start_consuming()
```

First i run `task_sender.py` to send ten jobs and it goes well .

But when i start two `worker.py` in different shell , It seems that only one worker is fetching tasks and another one is doing nothing .

What's more , when the working `worker` finish all the job in queue , I run `task_sender.py` again to send new tasks , the None of the `workers` fetch jobs any more .

It seems rabbitmq is working blocking , how can i solve that ?

This is my [Rabbitmq status](https://gist.github.com/KIDJourney/e7d142b69d1ec1c3f2ba)

Any help is welcomed , thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your worker, try to set prefetch_count to a reasonable value and set no_ack to false:

```
...
channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
channel.basic_consume(callback,
                  queue='task_queue',
                  no_ack=False)
...
```

Comment: It works , I will check the document for more detail , thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about pika but I faced the same issue when using oslo.messaging with rabbitmq as the backend. What happened was, the producer of the notification message sent it and the first listener (consumer) to catch the message consumed it, and the other listeners never got it.

For oslo there is a feature 'fanout', which sends the notification message to all servers instead of the 'first one winners, others losers' kind of style.

I think pika probably also has something like this.

[Oslo notification server documentation](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/oslo.messaging/server.html)

Try searching for keyword 'fanout' here. Then you can check if pika documentation has something similar or not. Hope this helps.